# In C why does my clearList function not work

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to clear a list. I keep getting an error that says free() called on an unallocated pointer current. I'm not sure what the problem is I have seen multiple sites use this code.

This is the whole program upon request:
I am only suppose to fill in these three functions.

```
#include "orderedList.h"

Node *orderedInsert(Node *p, int newval)
/* Allocates a new Node with data value newval
   and inserts into the ordered list with 
  first node pointer p in such a way that the
 data values in the modified list are in 
nondecreasing order as the list is traversed.
 */

{
Node * q = NULL;
q = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
q->data = newval;
q->next = NULL;

if (q == NULL)
{
    return q;
}

if (p == NULL || newval <= p->data )
{
    q->next = p->next;
    return q;
}

Node *tmp, *last;
tmp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));   
tmp = p;

while (tmp->next != NULL && tmp->data <= newval) 
{
    last = tmp;
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
q->next = tmp;
last->next = q;
return p;
}

void printList(FILE *outfile, Node *p)

/* Prints the data values in the list with 
   first node pointer p from first to last,
   with a space between successive values.
   Prints a newline at the end of the list.
*/

{
    Node* temp = p;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
       printf("%d ", temp->data);
       temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
   }

void clearList(Node **p)
/* Deletes all the nodes in the list with 
   first node pointer *p, resulting in *p
  having value NULL.  Note that we are passing
   a pointer by address so we can modify that 
   pointer.
*/
{
    Node* current = *p;
    Node* temp;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        temp = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = temp;
    }
    *p = NULL;
}
```

Comment: creation the element of  list is not used `malloc` family.

Comment: I am still a beginner where would I use malloc?

Comment: To be used when you create an element of the list.

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: Do you how create a list? post your code.

Comment: If `q == NULL`, what were you doing in the previous lines, assigning to `q->data` and `q->next`? :)

Answer (score 1):

sample code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

Node *orderedInsert(Node *p, int newval){
    Node *q;
    if(NULL==(q = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)))){
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    q->data = newval;
    q->next = NULL;

    if (p == NULL || newval <= p->data ){
        q->next = p;
        return q;
    }

    Node *tmp = p, *last;
    while (tmp != NULL && tmp->data < newval) {
        last = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    q->next = tmp;
    last->next = q;
    return p;
}

void printList(FILE *outfile, Node *p){
    Node* temp = p;
    while(temp != NULL){
        fprintf(outfile, "%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    fprintf(outfile, "\n");
}

void clearList(Node **p){
    Node* current = *p;

    while(current != NULL){
        Node *temp = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = temp;
    }
    *p = NULL;
}

int main (void){
    Node *head = NULL;
    int i, v;

    printf("The generated number\n");
    for(i=0; i<10; ++i){
        v = rand()%10;
        printf("%d ", v);
        head = orderedInsert(head, v);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("The orderd number\n");
    printList(stdout, head);

    clearList(&head);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is fundamentally ok, supposing that you don't need to free anything other than the `Node` objects themselves.  The problem is likely with your list.  In particular, if it contains a loop then you will see the behavior you describe, because your function will eventually come back to a `Node` it has already freed.

Comment: a real good reason to set the pointer to the free'd memory to NULL

Comment: @user3629249, yes, sort of.  If the problem is indeed because the list contains a loop then the setting the freed pointers to `NULL` would avoid the error.  It would not, however, bring to light the error *elsewhere* that causes a loop in the first place, and it would likely yield a memory leak in place of the error.  Personally, I'd rather get the error so that I know there's a problem.  (Avoiding setting freed pointers to `NULL` is by no means sure to achieve that, though, nor is it without problems of its own.)

Answer (score 0):

```
please read my added comments regarding the OPs code 

#include "orderedList.h"

Node *orderedInsert(Node *p, int newval)
/* Allocates a new Node with data value newval
   and inserts into the ordered list with
  first node pointer p in such a way that the
 data values in the modified list are in
nondecreasing order as the list is traversed.
 */

{
Node * q = NULL;
q = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
q->data = newval; // if q is NULL, then setting an offset from address 0
                  // which is a real good way to cause a seg fault event
q->next = NULL;   // if q is NULL, then setting an offset from address 0
                  // which is a real good way to cause a seg fault event

if (q == NULL)
{
    return q; // odd, returning a null,
              // I would expect to return p
}

if (p == NULL || newval <= p->data )
{
    q->next = p->next;  // odd, if p was null (I.E. adding first entry into list)
                        // then p->next is some offset from address 0
                        // a real good way to cause a seg fault event
                        // if not first entry in list and new data < first entry in list data
                        // then set q->next to be inserted before the current/existing list
                        // however, 
                        // (assuming p is the head of the list and not a ptr to the first entry)
                        //  then p->next needs to be set to q
    return q;
}

Node *tmp, *last;
tmp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)); // failed to check if malloc was successful
tmp = p;  // overlays the pointer to the 'just' malloc'd memory
          // and a good way to cause a seg fault event if malloc failed
-- I stopped checking the code here --

while (tmp->next != NULL && tmp->data <= newval)
{
    last = tmp;
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
q->next = tmp;
last->next = q;
return p;
}

void printList(FILE *outfile, Node *p)

/* Prints the data values in the list with
   first node pointer p from first to last,
   with a space between successive values.
   Prints a newline at the end of the list.
*/

{
    Node* temp = p;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
       printf("%d ", temp->data);
       temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
   }

void clearList(Node **p)
/* Deletes all the nodes in the list with
   first node pointer *p, resulting in *p
  having value NULL.  Note that we are passing
   a pointer by address so we can modify that
   pointer.
*/
{
    Node* current = *p;
    Node* temp;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        temp = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = temp;
    }
    *p = NULL;
}
```